# React and forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref, react-hoc

I have the following component which transforms checkbox into nice toggle switch

```
const ToggleSwitch = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  return (
    <div className={`toggle btn btn-lg>
      <input type='checkbox' onChange={handleOnChange} ref={ref} />
      <div className='toggle-group'>
        <label htmlFor={`toggle-${uniqueId}`} className={`btn btn-success btn-lg toggle-on`} ref={labelOn}>In Use</label>
        <label htmlFor={`toggle-${uniqueId}`} className={`btn btn-danger btn-lg toggle-off`} ref={labelOff}>Not in Use</label>
        <span className={`toggle-handle btn btn-light btn-lg`} ref={handle}></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Iam having an issue understanding how forward ref works and iam getting some errors. It is possible as well that iam confused by HOC components too

If i called this from different component like this:

```
 <ToggleSwitch checked={false} toggleName='monitoring' ref={(e) => {monitoring.current = e;register(e);}}/>
```

it works as expected without any issues. However if i call it as per below:

I have a table component which get data from body:

```
 const body = [{ key: 'inUse', type: 'component', component: ToggleSwitch, props: { checked: 'inUse', onChange: onToggleChange } }, { key: 'vlan' }, { key: 'clientId' }];
```

Each key is column. Now in table component i have a switch based on type.
If type = "component"

```
return <td>{component({ ...field.props, checked: entry[field.props.checked], entry: entry })}</td>
```

In here i get an error:
Uncaught TypeError: component is not a function

Any help would be appreciated. I have looked through similar questions but couldnt find any solution. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not invoke your components directly, but pass them into [`createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) function:

```js
return (
  <td>
    {createElement(component, {
      ...field.props,
      checked: entry[field.props.checked],
      entry: entry,
    })}
  </td>
);
```

You can also use JSX here, but with JSX you will have to name your `component` property with capital letter, so transformation would not confuse it with html or custom element.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I found the JSX just after i posted the question but your solutions seems neater :-) Works perfectly